# $E(u x)=0$ and endogeneity

Tags: linear, endogeneity, projection

I am confused as to how Endogeneity arises. I understand all the examples but something basic just doesn't fit: The usual assumption is that $E(xu) \ne 0$. But, we can always find $\beta$'s that satisfy this criterion, i.e., the linear projection. So why can't we always just project and then our estimates won't be correlated with the error?

Comment: Because the expression "$E(xu)\ne 0$" does not contain "$\beta$" anywhere, could you please explain the connection you see between the two?  In particular, by "$\beta$" do you mean a *true* parameter in a model or a *fitted* parameter?

Comment: Say you have two random variables $y$ and $x$. You can project y on $x$. The error is going to be uncorrelated with $x$.

Comment: You may be confusing the *residual* when you fit a model with the *error term* in the model itself.

Answer (score 2):

Consider three zero-mean  random variables $$Y, X, Z$$ that have a joint trivariate normal distribution, and are correlated with each other.

Define $e_x$ to be the Conditional Expectation function error related to  $E(Y\mid X)$ and $e_{xz}$ to be the conditional expectation function error related to $E(Y\mid \{X,Z\})$. By construction, we have

$$Y = E(Y\mid X) + e_x$$

$$Y = E(Y\mid \{X,Z\}) + e_{zx}$$

Since they are jointly normal, the conditional expectation functions will be linear so we have

$$Y = \alpha X + e_x$$

$$Y = \beta X + \gamma Z + e_{zx}$$

Note carefully that the coefficient on $X$ *changes* between the two specifications, as we should expect. *Both* specifications are valid, both describe *different true stochastic/statistical* relations among the variables.

Assume that you obtain data from $Y$ and $X$ and you specify a linear regression,

$$Y = aX + u$$

and you estimate $a$ by Ordinary Least Squares, i.e. by a projection of $Y$ on $X$. It is then true that

$$\text{plim} \hat a = \alpha \neq \beta$$

So the estimator $\hat a$ is consistent for $\alpha$, but inconsistent for $\beta$. The concept of "endogeneity" arises, *when we want to estimate the true parameter $\beta$ by using only data on $Y$ and $X$.*

In other words, it is indeed true that least-squares projection is always consistent for the parameter that *corresponds to the relation imposed by the data at hand* -which may not be the parameter of interest.

So "endogeneity" is a *relative* concept - relative to the purposes of the specific research target, acknowledging that there is not a single true determination of $Y$ - there are many different *stochastic* relations. The "single true determination" is the traditional approach inherited by the deterministic-engineering-physics approach to the matter.

Comment: A minor addendum: 'The "single true determination"...traditional approach inherited by the deterministic-engineering-physics approach' is also, for related reasons, the one you actually want for causal inference, which is relevant because endogeneity is a causal concept. When one wants to know the change in Y to be expected from a change in X, then there really is only one such quantity, which could be $\alpha$, $\beta$, both, or neither, depending on structure not specified by P(X,Y,Z).

Comment: @conjugateprior Thank you for your comment. The challenge with the (noble) quest for causality, is to not forget that at least for our times, the full causal specification of a social relation appears ever out of reach, and so trying to mend endogeneity in practice will only partially lead us towards this "one such quantity", if, that is, it actually there is "only one such quantity".

Comment: No disagreement here. The full causal specification is always out of reach - just like the full statistical specification. So our analysis is always conditional on them. Indeed I guess that's exactly your point, made for causality.

Answer (score 1):

> The usual assumption is that $E(xu)\ne0$. But, we can always find $\beta$'s that satisfy this criterion

Nope. The main problem is that $u$ here refers to *errors* not *residuals*. The former are **unobservable** while the latter is an **estimate** of the former.

When we write the model specification as $$y=X\beta+u$$
we mean to say that *observed* $y$ is related to observed $x$ via **unknown** coefficients $\beta$, and that random errors $u$ get into the observations of $y$ making it difficult (basically, impossible) to imply exact $\beta$'s. In the equation for *strict* endogeneity which you gave, it is this *unobserved* $u$ that enters.

We can run OLS and get **estimates** $\hat\beta,\hat u$, where the latter is also called *residuals*. Note, how we have two free variables $\hat\beta$ and $\hat u$ to play with, and two given observed inputs $x,y$. So, you can chose $\hat u$ in different ways, and they will define what will $\hat\beta$ be and vice versa.

Yes, in fact, the residuals $\hat u$ will be uncorrelated with independent variables $x$ by design of OLS when you find coefficient estimates $\hat\beta$, but that's not what endogeneity is talking about, it's talking about the *true* errors $u$